# How can I best visualize & compare this data? Should I create weighted composite variables for a scatter plot?

Tags: dataset, survey, composite

I have data from a survey which was asked people 1) how often they used a particular tool (daily, weekly, monthly, annually, etc) and 2) many hours they usually spent using it (0 - 4 hrs, 5 - 9, 10 - 14, and so on)

**My ultimate goal is to compare access frequency and usage amounts between different tools and identify tools that are high in both categories.**

--

I have the percentage of each response thats look something like this:

```
Tool A:

**Usage**
0 to 4 hours per week    5%
5 to 9 hours per week    6%
10 to 14 hours per week  20%
etc...

**Access**:
Multiple times per day   32%
Once a day               23%
A few times per week     31%
etc...
```

Is it feasible to create a weighted composite variable for each category assigning 1-x ? So the lowest category would be a 1 and the highest would be an 8 (for example). Then multiply each category by the percentage of responses so if it's the lowest category (e.g., 0 to 4 hours that would be a score of 1 multiplied by 5% response rate).

I would then sum up the weighted scores to get a composite variable for "Usage" and a second composite variable "Access"

From there once I have 2 composite scores I want to plot on a scatter plot to visualize usage vs access frequency and compare across tools for the most popular / heavily utilized ones.

Is something like that okay? Is there another way that would be recommended to visual the data in a scatter plot?

Thanks.

Comment: I may not understand your data correctly, but I'm not sure scatter plot is the best way to visualize here. Wouldn't frequency plots with usage hours categories on x-axis, counts on y-axis, and tool type as color coded work (and a similar plot for access categories)?

Comment: Yes that works, but I would need 2 independent graphs for usage and access. I wouldn't be able to view them on one chart, right?

Comment: I was thinking of 2 charts side by side but it might be possible to put them in the same chart too with some kind of more elaborate color/texture coding.

Comment: Side by side I'd have to scan side to side to identify tools high in both categories, that's why I was hoping with a single variable to capture that. Also might be too small to fit the two graphs on one slide.

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't think that kind of composite score makes sense, mostly because ranking the items that way distorts the data. Instead, for usage, if you want to find some single number summary, you could use the mean or median of each category:

$2*0.05 + 7*0.06  + 12*0.20 \dots$

and something similar for access. You would have to make some guess for the mean of the unbounded top category. You could try several and see how it varies.

Second, if you make a scatter plot, you'd need to add jitter to show the points, but I am not sure this is best. You might simply want a crosstabs, or you might want a mosaic plot.

Third, if you want to identify tools that are high in both, you don't need any plots. Just look for ones that are high in both. You could do this with IF THEN statements.

(Note also that, for some reason, your two variables are ordered in opposite ways, one from most to least use and the other from least to most).

Third,

Comment: That's fair regarding the distortion.  Not sure if I can generate a Mosiac plot in Excel / Google Sheets but I will explore options. Thanks! Let me know if you have a tool recommendation to visualize this.

Comment: Oh please don't use Excel for statistics or, especially, for graphics!  Almost anything is better. I am familiar with R and SAS but there are other options. Excel's default graphs are horrible.